# TypeError: customers.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this problem, can anyone help me?
TypeError: customers.map is not a function.
I've always used it that way and I've never had any problems.
Its about data integration.
Basically is that, please anyone can help me?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { List, Card } from "antd";
import { data } from "../../../mocks/customers";
import { DeleteCustomerButton } from "@components/atoms/DeleteCustomerButton";
import { CustomersEditButton } from "@components/atoms/CustomersEditButton";
import { useContext } from "../../../contexts/context";

const { Meta } = Card;

const CustomersCardList: React.FC = () => {
    const customers: any = useContext();

    return (
        <div>
            {customers.map((customer, key) => { })}</div>)
}

//context.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const AccountContext = React.createContext({});

export const useContext = () => React.useContext(AccountContext);

interface AccounterContextProviderProps {
    value: any
};

export const AccounterContextProvider: React.FC<AccounterContextProviderProps> = ({ children, value }) => {

    const [customers, setCustomers] = React.useState<any>([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const getCustomers = async () => {
            const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:3333/customers");
            setCustomers(result.data);
        }
        getCustomers();
    }, []);

    console.log(customers);

    return (
        <AccountContext.Provider value={{ ...value, customers }}>
            {children}
        </AccountContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is also available in spanish at https://es.stackoverflow.com. When asking on the english website, please use english.

Comment: @Eduardo Colissi Wiceskoski if you don't speak english, feel free to use any available online translator. Don't afraid if it will be a bit rusty.

Comment: Please share minimum reproducible example withour relative imports

Answer (score 1):

Any can be anything not only array, so it will not have a `map` method. Use `const customers:any[] = useContext()` instead

Comment: Hi thanks, but when I put this way, it returns this error: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.

Comment: That I can't tell unless I debug. May be provide you context code, then can tell

Comment: I added my context, if you can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: from my debugging I found your use context returns an empty object. From your context I can see that because you did React.createContext({}). I am not familiar with useContext hook so I can't help there. But from my debugging your getCustomers function from context.tsx never gets called.
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hooks-p2fcc?file=/src/context.tsx You can see here I tried to log inside getCustomers which yields nothing